# Troubles with the installing of package vectorbt in Python

Tags: python, pip, llvmlite

I´m trying to install the package vectorbt by Jupyter Notebook using the command below:

```
!pip install vectorbt
```

Occurs that the process doesn´t conclude and the following message error appears after the results lines below:

> "... Installing collected packages: llvmlite, numba, vectorbt
> Attempting uninstall: llvmlite Found existing installation: llvmlite
> 0.34.0 ERROR: Cannot uninstall 'llvmlite'. It is a distutils installed project and thus we cannot accurately determine which files belong to
> it which would lead to only a partial uninstall."

Anyone can help me?

Since then, I appreciate.

Comment: I would recommend installing into an environment or using a `--user` setting.

Comment: This won't help you here because of the complexity of dependencies with this particular package, @Marcel; however, it may improve your Jupyter experience later... Instead of using an exclamation with pip in a notebook, use the newer magics added to insure the installations done inside the notebook are in the correct enviornment. Anything listing an exclamation with either `pip` or `conda` is outdated. Use `%pip` or `%conda`. See [here](https://discourse.jupyter.org/t/why-users-can-install-modules-from-pip-but-not-from-conda/10722/4?u=fomightez) for more information about those modern magics.

Comment: Additional, related FYI... because in modern Jupyter environments automagics are usually on by default, you'll get the magic command equivalents being used if you use no symbol in front of `pip` or `conda` generally. I prefer keeping the `%` symbol so that it is explicit the line magic version of `pip`/`conda` is being used to others and your future self; however, it *often* isn't necessary now.

Comment: Hi Wayne. It doesn´t work too. I tryed with and without "%" before the pip, but the error still there.